# Redirect to page according to url path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is that possible to redirect to page accordingly for example  http://mysite.com/page.html to http://mysite.com/10010/page1.html (where cookies set to 10010); http://mysite.com/page2.html to http://mysite.com/10010/page2.html (where cookies set to 10010) and so on.

```
if ($.cookie('10010'))
{
 window.location.href = 'http://mysite.com/10010'+'what to insert here?';
}
```

Can I do it just with one string or I have to declare every page ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript

Comment: @Ashish yes thanks I know that, problem is that I have many pages..so I asked do I have to declare every page or there is a way to do it for all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a good way to handle cookies. You'd better of doing something like this

Setting up a cookie

```
var mylocation = window.location.href.split("/")[1];
$.cookie("mylocation", mylocation);
```

Getting your location

```
var mylocation = $.cookie("mylocation");
if( mylocation ) {
    window.location.href = "/"+mylocation+window.location.href;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply..is there any possibility to use something like {path} in my code..sorry im new to this..your example is very useful but the problem is that i will have to create and declare 100's of "mylocation"

Comment: Edited as per your request. It now stores `10010` in `http://mysite.com/10010/page1.html`

Comment: thanks..edited code didnt worked for me sorry..i probably have difficulties to explain what im trying to accomplish..with your first example there was an actual redirect in a way i need,just something wrong with path as it was redirecting to http://mysite.com/10010/http:mysite.com/page1.html..              that would be almost what i need if i could correct path in url..

Comment: In my case I have replicated folders,such as /10010/,/10011/ and so on  . Here is what is my problem..by now i accomplished to delete and set cookies according to my nneeds and  simply redirect users at http://mysite.com/10010 (or 10011,etc) what can be frustrating .For example, if a user visited a specific page, such as http://www.mysite.com/10010/page1.html,even if he types http://www.mysite.com/page1.html he will be redirected to http://www.mywebsite/10010.. i want him to be redirected to http://www.mysite.com/10010/page1.html